# How to connect with JMX from host to Docker container in Docker machine?

Tags: tomcat, networking, docker, jmx, docker-machine

When I have running Docker container directly at my host, it is possible to connect to it without any problems.

My host has network 192.168.1.0/24 and IP address of the host is 192.168.1.20. My Docker container has IP address 172.17.0.2. When I connect to 172.17.0.2:1099 from jconsole it works.

When I put this service into Docker machine, it is not possible to connect to it.

My Docker machine has IP 192.168.99.100 and container in it has IP address 172.17.0.2 but when I use jconsole to connect to 192.168.99.100:1099 it does not work.

To repeat it:

192.168.1.20 --- 172.17.0.2:1099 works

192.168.1.20 --- (192.168.99.100 --- 172.17.0.2:1099) and connecting to 192.168.99.100:1099 from my host does not work.

It is worth to say that I can access services containerized in Docker machine via external IP address of the Docker machine, e.g. this will work:

192.168.99.100 --- (192.168.99.100:8080 --- 172.17.0.2:8080)

But when I use JMX it just does not work.

It is Tomcat service. I have this in scripts which starts Tomcat instance:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP address of Docker container
```

Comment: It is started by docker-java library ... it is not so important, but when I do "docker-machine ssh" and in it "docker ps -a" I can see that my container has this port bindings / exposings: ad6be9184855        company/tomcat:8.0.30 0.0.0.0:1099->1099/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8009->8009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is probably the value of the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property. This needs to be the hostname or IP address that should be used by the JMX client to connect to your JVM. That is in the first case where you connect to your container directly using `172.17.0.2:1099`, this setting needs to be set to `172.17.0.2`. In the latter case where you access the container through the docker machine on `192.168.99.100:1099`, the setting needs to be set to `192.168.99.100`.

During my research for a very similar question (which was deleted in the meantime) I stumbled across a blog entry (which was deleted in the meantime as well). Although It's rather old it gave me an idea how the JMX connectivity works:

1. The JMX registry listens on port `<com.sun.management.jmxremote.port>` of the container
2. If you connect to the registry with JConsole, the registry provides the JMX service URL to the client.
3. This URL is used by the client to obtain the JMX objects

The service URL looks like this `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<java.rmi.server.hostname>:<com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port>/jmxrmi`. That is in your case `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://172.17.0.2:1099/jmxrmi`. As this address is only reachable from within the docker machine, connecting from remote is not possible. In my question I cover the same problem in regards to the RMI port...

There doesn't seem to be an out-of-the-box solution to this problem. However one can provide both JMX port and the external hostname (or IP) on startup of the container as environment variables, as suggested [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/exposing-mapped-jmx-ports-from-multiple-containers/5287). These could then be used in the JMX config:

```
docker run -p 1099:1099 \
    -e "JMX_HOST=192.168.99.100" \
    -e "JMX_PORT=1099" \
    company/tomcat:8.0.30
```

and

```
CATALINA_OPTS="... \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$JMX_HOST"
```

Not very nice, but it should work...

Comment: yes this approach works and I have figured it out exactly like you, I have just forgotten to write an answer :) Thanks.

Comment: BTW: This worked for me as well (Java 7, Tomcat 7), but I also had to add `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=` in the `CATALINA_OPTS` to get it to work. Just having the individual properties was not sufficient.

Comment: @nwinkler of course you're right. I updated my answer to include the missing system property `com.sun.management.jmxremote`

Comment: Note that you might still run into problems regarding the port mapping. The internal port must be equal to the external port of the docker container (which must be equal to the `$JMXPORT`-var). Otherwise the Stubs returned by the JMX-registry will not be able to connect. Additionally your Dockerfile needs to expose all potential ports ever used for JMX, which is practically infeasible. **TLDR**: Better use something else for monitoring

Comment: @fab You don't have to use EXPOSE in the Dockerfile, it can also be defined at runtime: [docker run --expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).

Comment: This all breaks down under Kubernetes because hostname isn't known until runtime and changes if the service is restarted for any reason by the system

Comment: @slashdottir I'm not much into kubernetes (yet) but if you can determine the name of your host before starting the JVM you could do the same as above. I think kubernetes has it's own DNS - if I recall correctly - that could be used to get the current hostname?! However stuff like JMX and RMI are not really what you want for a cloud-native application...

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has problems with it. I have started the java process in the docker container with the following parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9876 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<name of the docker container>
```

The important part is to set the name of the docker container. EXPOSE the port in the container 9876. I have also setup an ssh connection and forwarded 9876 to the localhost.

The following goes to your SSH config:

```
LocalForward 127.0.0.1:9876 127.0.0.1:9876
```

Also I have setup /etc/hosts on the local machine

```
127.0.0.1 <name of the docker container>
```

Now connect your console to "name of the docker container"