# Play Framework (2.5) - JMX port enable to see in JVisualVM

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator, activator

I am trying to see threads management of Play application. Need to use JVisualVm to see the threads running. Basically, the JMX port should be enabled to see the Play Application. I am using Play 2.5 with Activator. Using **acivator run** command to run the application and configuration the Java Args in the build.sbt file like below.

```
javaOptions ++= Seq(
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote",
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5678",
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false",
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
   "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.11.1.18"
)
```

But nothing works with the above configuration. Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: What exactly JVisualVM tells you while trying to connect?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why JMX client cannot connect to your server may be a firewall refusing connections to `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` which is randomly assigned by default, so you can set it explicitly to the same value as `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` for convenience.

Another reason may be due to wrong value for `java.rmi.server.hostname`, it must be the same ip address as you're using to access the application using browser.

So, your configuration may look like this:

```
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5678"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5678"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false "
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
javaOptions += "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.11.1.18" // make sure it's your app's web address
```

If nothing helps, refer to [VisualVM Troubleshooting Guide](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/troubleshooting.html).

Also check the resources below for more info on similar issues (they're about docker, but it's essentially the same as connecting to remote host using jmc):

- [How to connect with JMX from host to Docker container in Docker machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466461/how-to-connect-with-jmx-from-host-to-docker-container-in-docker-machine)
- [Remote Java Debugging With Docker](https://ptmccarthy.github.io/2014/07/24/remote-jmx-with-docker/)